# Visual Studio Project purpose & templates for ASP.NET Rendering SDK application

Tags: jss, helix, jss-rendering-sdk

This is how the Helix example is structured and I'm trying to understand it.

[image]

The *.rendering in the `Project` layer looks like an ASP.NET Core template but the *.rendering projects in the `Feature` layer look like Class Library/Console App. Why is it different?

Please let me know what should be the template for creating the *.rendering & *.platform projects (e.g. Console app, MVC app, .Net core app, class library etc).

I understand the purpose of Feature, Foundation & Project layers. But for developing a Headless architechture with .Net core Rendering SDK, I'm unable to understand what should be in the *.platform & what should be in *.rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I learned during the `Sitecore 10` development, there are two kinds of projects we use while Developing with the `ASP.NET Core Rendering SDK`. They are as follows.

- **RenderingHost project**: It is the primary project and is considered the startup project which will run when debugging in `Visual Studio`. The `RenderingHost` project is also where you’ll be creating models and views necessary to support custom components. The `Startup.cs` class within the Rendering project is also where these views can be registered for use within `Sitecore`.
- **Platform project**: Corresponds to the `Content Management container` and contains the code and configuration for that part of the Sitecore platform. To deploy any code changes to the configuration, assemblies, or content, this project will need to be published from `Visual Studio`. If changes are made to the `Platform` project, debugging is an optional, but recommended step. To debug the `Platform project`, you will need to attach it to the `w3wp` process within the Content Delivery container.

Now the architecture you are following is a `Helix` based architecture and you can see feature and foundation folders.

I hope I can answer your questions.

As mentioned in the `RenderingHost` project, it contains a `startup.cs` file that is used to register the views. So you can see in the `BasicCompany.Project.BasicCompany.Rendering`, they are using all the features `*.rendering` projects under the `Dependencies`

[image]

And registering them into the `Startup.cs` file using this statement.

```
  // Register the Sitecore Rendering Engine services.
        services.AddSitecoreRenderingEngine(options =>
        {
            //Register your components here
            options
                .AddFeatureBasicContent()
                .AddFeatureNavigation()
                .AddFeatureProducts()
                .AddFeatureServices()
                .AddDefaultPartialView("_ComponentNotFound");
        })
```

So the summary is that `Model-bound components` supported by a model and view must be registered within the `Startup.cs` class to be used in the `rendering host`. Thats' why they are being used as `Dependencies` under the `BasicCompany.Project.BasicCompany.Rendering` project and all the `Platform` projects are associated with their `feature` project. I think you need to use the same pattern as you get from the sample project.

I hope this makes sense.